# Vue Capacitor Ionic 4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: queue

Tags: vue.js, ionic4, capacitor

I've an issue with a vue/capacitor/Ionic 4 vanilla application when running electron and on android.

The error is as follow :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: queue
ionicpwaelements.rdkmyppq.js:122 

 Ionic:
  ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0
  System:
  NodeJS : v10.15.3
  npm    : 6.9.0
  OS     : macOS Mojave
```

[image: Error Message[1]]

Any idea the cause of this error ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: have you check what is queue in your code?

Comment: Actually, I don't use a queue in my code at all.  The error in a Ionic module called ionicpwaelements.rdkmyppq.js:122

Comment: what is ionic info in cmd?

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for, do you mean the dependencies in package.json ?

Comment: in command link type 'ionic info'

Comment: Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.3
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave